# How to add a line at the bottom of spinner as like edittext in android

Tags: android

Hello I am making demo application in which i am using `EditText` in which a line appears at the bottom that is ok but it is not in case of spinner.

How this is possible to do ?

layout.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/twitterEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/twitter_account"
    android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/country" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/stateSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/state" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/citySpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/city" />
```

[image]

Comment: You want something to display the user's choice after he chooses something in US list and so on?
Please be more clear...

Comment: @TomerZ i want there should be black line as same as like other view (edittext phone, email)

Comment: @TomerZ that line should be there always not after user pick something from a spinner

Comment: You want it to be like a seperator or to display the chosen option? (or just to be there, empty, if nothing was chosen yet)

Comment: @TomerZ this is like a separator but this is not a additional view i added in case of edittext. it is by default in android material design

Comment: I was struggling with this

Answer (score 135):

I just faced the same Problem and after researching for a while the answer is quite easy:

```
    <Spinner
        ...            
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        ... />
```

Comment: style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" is undefined.

Comment: How to change the color of the line ?

Comment: To change the color, you have to modify your style, like example:
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF9900</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF9900</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 40):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        ...            
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        app:backgroundTint="YOUR_COLOR_HERE"
        ... />
```

Answer (score 9):

If `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined` not found or not Working used below `style` to spinner for bottom Underlined

```
             <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
```

Answer (score 4):

Since no one has posted an actual answer, here ya go:

```
<item android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

That line is what you write your input above. A spinner doesn't have that line because it is not a text input field.
If you want to have a line below the spinner too, You could insert it below by faking it like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/firstSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/firstHint" />

<!-- Separator view -->

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/secondSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/secondHint" />

<!-- Insert separator view again-->
```

Probably you need to play around with the margins a bit. Also notice that the black line is only in Android 5.0, and the whole layout will look a lot different on older Androids. If you only want to have to black line on Android 5.0, then you have to make a copy of the layout, and insert it in a directory called `layout-v21`, and have the other version in the default `layout` directory.

Comment: I don't want to follow this approach. I want to do this via style and nine patch image.

Comment: this method do not work for me, only with `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"`

Answer (score 1):

**Its Working**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/holoSpinner</item>
</style>

<style name="holoSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#3F51B5</item>
</style>
```

**Happy Coding**